# Create a sequential diagram for each use case in the online shopping system

Tags: uml, software-design, sequence-diagram

[image]

According to this use case diagram, I have to draw a sequence diagram for each use case except login by making an assumption. For example, when I come to the checkout sequence diagram, I can assume that the procedure is done through view items, but in the view items sequence diagram, I must clearly draw the procedure sequence. I googled and learned about sequencial diagrams, but I didn't find anything like this. I'm trying to sketch some use cases, but for example, when it comes to completing checkout, there are many actors, and I'm not sure how to do it when there are more actors.

I created a sequence diagram for login, but I don't know if I have to take authentication as an actor or not. This is my sketch.

[image]

That is my login sketch, which I made.

I need just a guide on how to draw a complete checkout and make a purchase sequence diagram separately. like how we draw when we have several actors. Please give me some advice and instructions on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Tharindu, thanks for using Stackoverflow. I have voted to close this question, because you ask multiple questions: (1) Shall Authentication be an actor in the sequence diagram?  (2) Please create the checkout sequence diagram for me.  Furthermore, a Stackoverflow question shall not request the reader to draw a complete diagram from scratch. You shall always attempt to draw it yourself, show us what you did and ask one specific question about it. If you confine your question to "Is it allowed to have multiple actors in a sequence diagram", I will no longer vote this question to be closed.

Comment: Think about those bubbles. They are no use cases but functional decomposition.

Comment: I value the help you've given me. Thanks for the advice and support.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues, but the most important issue seems to be about how to deal with multiple actors in a sequence diagram. If you want to know how to create sequence diagrams for use cases that have an include relationship, please open a new question focusing on that issue.

One may include multiple actors in a sequence diagram. Usually, the primary actor is shown at the left-hand side of the sequence diagram and the secondary actors are shown at the right-hand side.

Strictly speaking, your sequence diagram will not contain actors, but it will contain so-called lifelines, representing elements of type actor. To refer to actor Customer, you could label the stickman `:Customer`.

Comment: You probably mixed that with UC diagrams where actors are positioned like that. An SD is not supposed to show actors but instances, though most tools allow it and making "fake start messages" is not uncommon.

Comment: @qwerty_so : A Lifeline in a sequence diagram does not represent an instance. It usually represents a ConnectableElement, which is the set of all instances that follow the sequence as modeled in the sequence diagram. And even this wording is not 100% precise. For OP, it is better not to go into these details.

Comment: Well, probably. The spec say _ConnectableElement is an abstract metaclass representing a set of instances that play roles of a StructuredClassifier._ Lifeline is detailed on p. 570. Anyhow, I think your basic statement about the actors does not apply.

Comment: @qwerty_so, I have added "Strictly speaking, your sequence diagram will not contain actors, but it will contain so-called lifelines, representing elements of type actor. To refer to actor Customer, you could label the stickman `:Customer`."

Comment: I still think that the left/right placement is only for UC diagrams (which is where it's common practice; not so for SDs), but else your answer is fine now.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl But actors are external to the system under consideration, whereas connectable elements of a sequence diagram shall belong to “an enclosing classifier“ (according tonthe specs), i.e be internal to the system. The only way to get actors in a sd, would be to consider a system of systems, but then, what was previously considered as actors are no longer actors but components of a larger system. Of course, that’s the theory, and in practice actors are often included in an sd and it seems to be a tolerated practice. Wouldn’t a slight warning about informality/ambiguity help?

Comment: @qwerty_so the left/right convention is indeed for use cases, (and I think to remember it was even rather difficult to find an authoritative source, not speak of the secondary vs supportive terminology). But I can from own observation confirm in many sds the tendency promoted by the admiral.  I think it is however more a consequence of  reducing arrows crossing lifelines (which shifts actors on opposite extreme sides), and cultural habits of left to-right writing (narratives often introduce primary actors first, they takenfirst free slot left)than the systematic transposition of UC conventions

Answer (score 1):

Well, a sequence diagram can have multiple actors, but according to this question, I think login is correct. Also, when you create the sequence diagram separately for complete checkout, there are no actors, and you can make whatever assumptions you want that are mentioned in the question above. I think this will help you sort out your problem a little bit.